# Math.log TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

Tags: python

I can't calculate float logarithm

```
logahr = math.log(float (1.54)*hr, 10)
             logfc = math.log(frek, 10)
             loght = math.log(ht, 10)
            #ahr formula
             ahre = (8.29 * logahr**2)- 1.1
            #pangkat formula
             pangkat = ((69.55+26.16*logfc)-13.83*loght-ahre)/(6.55*loght - 44.9)

             d = pow (10, float(pangkat))

             print(d)
```

> logahr = math.log(float (1.54)*hr, 10) TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

Comment: The error is in plain sight: hr is a sequence, probably a list, and you can't multiply a list with a float, only with an integer, but you get a list containing x times your list (where x is the int multiplied for your list, but probably that wasn't your purpose). You have to use a for over the elements of hr and then, inside, you do math.log(elem*1.54,10)

Comment: it is not necessarily that it is a sequence, it can be also a string or whatever what is not int or float number @crissal

Comment: Yeah you're right, I assumed list but every iterable can do the job

Answer (score 0):

before this line:

```
logahr = math.log(float (1.54)*hr, 10)
```

> in your variable `hr` you have `string`,`sequence`, or something else which is not integer or float number

if you have string:

```
logahr = math.log(float (1.54)*float(hr), 10)
```

if its sequence:

```
logahr = math.log(float (1.54)*float(hr[0]), 10)
```

> anyway check what type you have in variable `hr`